# Why would one use an applicationi load balancer over network load balancer in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm setting up an AWS load balancer and looking at the two options to pick from.  It seems that the network load balancer is capable of doing anything the application load balancer is capable of while being fuller featured *and* having a lower pricing cost per LCU, which leaves me wondering why the application load balancer is even offered.  The only possible advantage I could see is slight ease of configuration, but for me knowing that I already have the more fully featured load balancer, in case that need arises for more complex balancing I couldn't do with the application load balancer, seems worth the minor increased implementation cost.

Is there an advantage to the Application Load Balancer that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

ALB and NLB serve **different purposes**. Below I will list few, which in my option, are key ones.

ALB is used for HTTP/HTTPS traffic (layer 7), thus it has possibilities of inspecting HTTP headers, redirecting based on paths, query strings, and other HTTP specific functionality. None of the above is possible in NLB which is for TCP/UDP/TLS traffic (layer 4). Thus for serving websites or any other HTTP/HTTPS applications ALB provides much more features and its specially designed for these type of use-cases.

The other important advantage of ALB is that it supports **security groups** (SG). NLB does not support them, thus you have to basically fully open it up for the internet. With SGs you can limit ALB access to only specific IP ranges or individual ports (e.g. 80 or 443). Doing same in NACLs will affect everything else in the subnet, not only NLB. The only way to control access to NLB is through NACLs which have far less features than SGs, e.g. you can't reference one NACLs in other one and they are stateless.

Speaking of security, ALB supports [WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-waf.html), while NLB does not. This can protect your website from **variety of attacks**, such as cross-site scripting or SQL injection.

ALB also supports **lambda targets**, unlike NLB. Thus you can construct your load-balance applications based on lambda functions as well. This is often very useful.

**Sticky sessions** based on cookies are yet another feature of ALB, which is not present in NLB. And this is very useful if you have application that requires to keep user's session active.

There are many more differences, and they a comparison table of NLB and ALB is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/?nc=sn&loc=2):